# Describe someone who stays "True to themselves"

Tags: word-choice, idioms

What's another word or phrase for "*true to himself*"?

> He remains true to himself even when his friend is murdered.

In this case, let's say 'He' is some sort of activist whose friend is murdered by a gang wanting 'He' to shut up. However, 'He' does not shut up and continues to raise awareness for whatever it is the gang members do not want to draw attention to.

Basically, 'He' keeps doing what he knows is morally correct, despite something bad happening to him as a consequence.

Comment: Please add some context; also explain the meaning of the example sentence (*i.e.* of *true to himself* and *targeted*); and add an independent example.

Comment: Yes, now it's answerable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might say the individual didn't ***compromise his principles*** or didn't ***give in to pressure***.

Alternatively, you could say he ***persisted*** or ***persevered*** (in his beliefs).

Potential adjectives for such a person are ***incorruptible***, ***upright*** and ***steadfast***. (Obviously, there are many others).

A casual phrase that expresses this idea is ***to stick to one's guns***.

Answer (score 1):

- principled
- undeterred
- indomitable
- resolute
- staunch
- true blue
- Spartan
- undaunted

Comment: *indomitable* would be my preference

Answer (score 1):

Someone of good moral character might be said to possess *integrity*, but I know of no related adjective that is in current use.

Answer (score 0):

From Merriam Webster Online:

> **integrity**
>
> (noun) \in-ˈte-grə-tē\
>
> firm adherence to a code of especially moral or artistic values :  incorruptibility

So, "He has integrity." is a good way of saying ""He is true to himself". But in your context, "being true to himself" means he is **fearless** or he is **not intimidated**.